# How do I install a newer version of a program without deleting my settings

Tags: vb.net

Ok i have this txt file hosted that has the version of the latest version of the file.

Basically it works like this, there is a variable declared at the beginning of the program.

```
Dim Version = "1.0"
```

Whenever the program starts it reads the text file that i would update when there is a new update.

```
If Version = (text in the txt file) then  
(Code for downloading and installing the new program.)  
End If
```

Well I know how to download the file but how do I install the new version and keep all my old program settings from deleting.

Comment: I assume you won't save the settings in the same place of your program installation folder. You can save your settings in Application Data folder (`%appdata%`) or in registry (old style, not recommended).

Comment: And by the way - have a way to upgrade those old settings to new settings version. For example - you may have added a new property in the settings. Make sure you add that to the existing settings and upgrade it to latest version. That way application upgrades continuously upgrade the settings to be in sync with latest app version.

Comment: Mabye you dont understand, you know when you go into your project settings. And then click Settings and it gives you a way to make special variables that keep their values even after the program is closed. Thats what im talking about.

Comment: @Naqeeb They understand you perfectly. This is application configuration. It depends more on your installer than your code here. Your installer has to be designed to leave the settings file alone. If your installer deletes the settings file, you're out of luck in your program itself. Probably the best way to handle this is to not let your installer touch the settings file at all. Make the app generate it on first run; then the installer doesn't even know about the settings file. Also, your program should probably just launch the installer and then close itself to prevent file lock problems.

Comment: Ok then i dont understand what they are saying, im a beginner so i dont really understand these things.

Comment: Ok I have another idea, how about my installer copies the config files  that store the My.settings. Then when installation is complete the program overwrites the new config files with the old ones. Saving the old settings. The problem here is I dont know where the config files are and how to copy them to the new version.

Comment: @jpmc26 Ok instead of using settings i have decided to use textfiles in the resources. I know how to use resources that are embedded into the program, but I want to be able to copy and paste it into other programs so i set it to content. I then realized I could not access the resource by customary means could you tell me how i could read/write to the resource.

Comment: You don't know where the config file is? Then how can your installer delete it or overwrite it in the first place?

Comment: Ok i think i solved the problem, the installer will overwrite the old files in the program files folder. The settings files will remain untouched.